# defining a list within a function in python

Tags: python

```
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import cess_esp #corpus of spanish texts
new_tagged = [w for w in cess_esp.tagged_words() if w[1][0] == 'v'] #extract all verbs from the corpus
lowers = sorted([(w[0].lower(), w[1]) for w in new_tagged]) #lowercase the words, sort them alphabetically

uniends = ['ar','er','as','ad','ed',
'id','ase','an','en','es','\xc3\xa9is','emos', 'o'] #endings of conjugated verbs (it is actually much longer, but the endings are irrelevant to my question here)

uniends.sort(key=len, reverse=True) #rearrange in decreasing length, so the correct endings get cut off

def lem(list): #lemmatize a list of conjugated spanish verbs
    lems = [] #create an empty list for lemmas
    for t in list: #loop through the list
        if t[0] == 'ir': #first, account for some irregulars that would disappear
            stem = 'ir'
        if t[0] == 's\xc3\xa9':
            stem = 'sab'
            lems.append(stem) #add stems to lems
        for end in uniends: #loop through the list of endings
            if t[0].endswith(end): #if the verb has an ending (which they all do)
                stem = t[0][0:-len(end)] #cut off the ending
                if stem == 'pued' or stem == 'pud': #account for common irregulars.
                    stem = 'pod'
                if stem == 'estuv':
                    stem = 'est'
                if stem == 'cuent':
                    stem = 'cont'
                if stem == 'tien' or stem == 'tuv':
                    stem = 'ten'
                if stem == 'hiz' or stem == 'hag':
                    stem = 'hac'
                if stem == 'dij':
                    stem = 'dec'
                if stem == 'vist':
                    stem = 'v'
                if stem == 'jueg':
                    stem = 'jug'
                if stem == 'sup':
                    stem = 'sab'
                if stem == 'veng':
                    stem = 'ven'
                if stem =='hub' or stem == 'h':
                    stem = 'hab'
                lems.append(stem) #add the stem to the list of lemmas
    return lems
```

The function returns a list, lems, but then if I try to do anything with lems once the function has run, I get an error: name 'lems' is not defined. I thought I defined it as part of the function lem(list), in the second line, and then filled it by appending stems to it. How can I get my function to make this list one that I can work with after I have run the function on a list?

Comment: Try doing `lems = lem(whatever_you_call_lem_on)`

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the function and where the error happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lems only define in function lem, and when you return, you did not assign it to any one, so one way is to put lems as gloabl item, another way is to assign len result to someone.

something like:

```
lems = []
def lem(list): #lemmatize a list of conjugated spanish verbs
    global lems
    ...
```

or

```
lems2 = lem(...)
```

I don't want to

```
lems = lem(...)
```

because I don't know other part of your code.